# Access values of raster/terra object from Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-raster, terra

Is there a way to read cell values of a raster or terra object from inside Rcpp? Currently I convert the object to a vector and access via cell (or row/col):

*Rcpp:*

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double value_from_cell(const Rcpp::NumericVector &x, const int cell) {
  double out = x[cell-1];
  return out;
}
```

*R:*

```
library(terra)

# Create a SpatRaster from scratch
x <- rast(nrows = 108, ncols = 21, xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
          vals = runif(108*21))

# Convert to vector
x_vec <- terra::values(x, mat = FALSE)


value_from_cell(x = x_vec, cell = 20)
```

I know I can access basic information (e.g. ncol, xmin, ..) via `Rcpp::S4` as seen in the [fasterize](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/fasterize/blob/master/src/edge.h) package. But it would be great to read values directly from within Rcpp, since the conversion to a vector is very RAM expensive or might even be to large. Any help/guidance would be great!

Comment: I have to admit I read this a few times and I still don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: I think you should provide some context about the bigger question of what you are trying to achieve.  It is possible this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and there could be a better approach (such as, e.g. using `app` to apply an Rcpp function to a raster).

Comment: My apologies for the unclear post.
I need an alternative argument for `NumericVector &x` . I would like to access the values of an terra/raster object directly from within Rcpp, without prior conversion to a value-vector.

Comment: You would need to write accessors / mappers between what Rcpp can provide back to / from R (in `SEXP` form) and what raster / terra have.  See the [Extending Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) vignette -- and/or look at existing packages in the geospatial space such as [terra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html) which already seem to be doing something along the lines you desire.